# How can I read an XML File and put the info in objects?

Tags: c#, xml, object, xmlreader

I have a function which writes all the Information of objects I have in a list into a XML file.

```
    public static void UpdateXML()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter Writer = XmlWriter.Create("path", settings);
        Writer.WriteStartDocument();
        Writer.WriteStartElement("Accounts");
        foreach (var acc in Bank.Bankaccountlist)
        {
            Writer.WriteStartElement("Account");
            Writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", acc.id.ToString());
            Writer.WriteElementString("Name", acc.GetName());
            Writer.WriteElementString("Lastname", acc.GetLastname());
            Writer.WriteElementString("Balance", acc.GetBalance().ToString());
            Writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        Writer.WriteEndElement();
        Writer.Flush();
        Writer.Close();
    }
```

Now, when the Program gets closed, all the Data is still in the file. So as soon as the Program starts again, it should create all the old objects again (creating an `Account` object will automatically put it in the list).

Could anyone tell me how that'd be possible?

Note that `int id` and `double balance`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: "It didn't work" is and will never be an accurate description of a problem. *Why* didn't it work? What have you tried? Are there error messages? Can you provide us and [mcve] so we can recreate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to following solution:

```
public static void ReadXML()
{
    DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();
    xmlData.ReadXml("path");

    foreach (DataTable table in xmlData.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Account newAcc = new Account(row.ItemArray[0].ToString(), row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(row.ItemArray[2]), Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[3]));
            }
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

This can 100% be improved, but it's works.

Answer (score 0):

To give an answer depending on your actual solution, you should use a `XmlReader` as counterpart of your `XmlWriter`. For every property type other than string you should use `Convert` or the appropriate `TryParse` method. But you may have a look at the `XmlSerializer` which targets exactly your usecase.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

You would also have to mark each part of the o jet as an xml attribute in order to serialize the object to xml.  Then you can loop through the files in the xml directory and deserialize them, using the xml reader.  I believe there is a nuget package to help with this.